# reading variables in parallel in while loop

Tags: bash

Why is this coding getting "ambiguous redirect" error for reading two variables in parallel? I must use while or for loop, can't use "paste"

```
#!/bin/bash
export fname="Adam Baden Caydin"
export lname="Sam Tam Uam"
while read first_name <$fname && read last_name <$lname
do
echo $first_name "    :    " $last_name
echo "doing some processing here..... "
done
```

***Error:*** .*/f1.sh: line 4: $fname: ambiguous redirect*

Replacing last line "done" with gives same result

```
done <<< "$fname $lname"
```

***Error:*** ./f1.sh: line 4: $fname: ambiguous redirect

**Expected Output**

```
Adman Sam
Baden Tam
Caydin Uam
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `read`. Why not make them arrays?

Comment: `read` reads a whole line, not one word at a time.

Comment: Why are you exporting the variables?

Comment: @UlisesAndréFierro What variable is he re-declaring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` expects each input to be on a separate line, so you have to replace the spaces with newlines. And to read the names in parallel, you need to combine the corresponding items into the same line of input. You can do this with the `paste` command.

```
paste <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$fname") <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$lname") | while read first_name last_name
do
echo $first_name : $last_name
done
```

Oops, didn't notice the constrain against using `paste`. Another solution is to use arrays instead of strings:

```
fname=(Adam Baden Caydin)
lname=(Sam Tam Uam)
i=0
for first_name in "${fname[@]}"
do
    last_name=${lname[$i]}
    echo $first_name : $last_name
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: I like this, but OP said "can't use paste."

Comment: @sjnarv Thanks, added an array solution as well.

Comment: thanks for solution for paste, it works :)    funny thing is that it doesn't work while /location/filename.csv  /location/filename2.csv  somehow it's not catching that space between them. going to research this. thanks for great solution :)

Comment: edit: i think it's because i have null value instead of white space because I did a run try and it worked, will post something when I get solution.

Comment: I thought you weren't allowed to use `paste`. I don't understand what those filenames are for, I thought the whole point is that the data is in variables, not files.